# Synology Web Station : GD WebP Support Missing

Tags: php, gd, synology, webp

Synology Web Station:
[image: Synology Web Station]

[image: Synology Web Station PHPInfo]

PHP imagejpeg() and imagepng() works, but imagewebp() not works.

My PHP version is 7.0, [Synology Web Station].

And I checked [gd plugin] in Web Station.

What's the problem?

Comment: Inline image; removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You should see `WebP Support` for gd in `phpinfo()` as following:

[image]

Comment: I using Synology Web Station. I checked all extensions. and I see phpinfo(). This php supports GD library, but, WebP support not found.

Comment: The ISP can support GD without wep support, I believe you encounterd this situation. Can you upload a php file with only `<?php phpinfo();` then use browser open the web to see the output? Only in this way you can confirm the support. If cannot find, you have nothing to do, just change service to host your php.